# Direct sum preserves exactness of Module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

I was thinking how do we prove Direct sum preserves exactness of modules using only universal property of modules.It's true that if we chase elementwise .[image: A term of commutative algebra;Allen ALTMAN and Steven KLEIMAN]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot entirely avoid elementwise arguments, as of course this statement is not true in general pointed categories with the necessary limits and colimits. I will only do the forward direction, so we suppose given this family $M'_\lambda\xrightarrow{f_\lambda} M_\lambda\xrightarrow{g_\lambda} M''_\lambda$ of exact sequences, indexed over $\lambda\in \Lambda$.

In order to show that $\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\Lambda}M'_\lambda\to \bigoplus_{\lambda\in\Lambda}M_\lambda\to \bigoplus_{\lambda\in\Lambda}M''_\lambda$ is also exact, we need to show that $\mathrm{im}(\oplus f_\lambda)=\mathrm{ker}(\oplus g_\lambda)$. We will use that $\mathrm{im}\,h=\mathrm{coker}(\mathrm{ker}(h))$ and that we have to show that the canonical comparison map $\mathrm{im}(\oplus f_\lambda)\to\mathrm{ker}(\oplus g_\lambda)$ is an isomorphism. Finite direct sums commute with all limits and colimits, because limits commute with limits and colimits commute with colimits. Moreover, in the category of modules, finite limits commute with filtered colimits (this is where we use that we work in modules, so this needs ''checking things on elements'', if you will). Since we can write any direct sum as a filtered colimit of finite direct sums, this implies that all direct sums commute with limits and colimits of modules. Therefore, $\mathrm{im}(\oplus f_\lambda)\cong\bigoplus\mathrm{im}\,f_\lambda$ and $\mathrm{ker}(\oplus g_\lambda)\cong\bigoplus\mathrm{ker}\,g_\lambda$. But now the comparison map $\bigoplus\mathrm{im}\,f_\lambda\to \bigoplus\mathrm{ker}\,g_\lambda$ is an isomorphism as direct sum of isomorphisms.

In order to show that $\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}M'_\lambda\to \prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}M_\lambda\to \prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}M''_\lambda$ is also exact, we proceed similarly. However, now we cannot use any tricks with filtered colimits, and it is false that cofiltered limits commute with finite colimits of modules. We can do the following: since limits commute with limits, to repeat the approach in the previous paragraph we only need to show that products commute with images of module homomorphisms. Since products preserve monomorphisms in categories with pullbacks (as $h\colon X\to Y$ being a monomorphism is equivalent then to $X$ being the pullback of the cospan $X\to Y\leftarrow X$), it holds that $\prod\mathrm{im}\,f_\lambda\hookrightarrow\prod M_\lambda$ is a monomorphism. Moreover, in the category of modules, products preserve epimorphisms as well (here, I don't see a way to avoid checking things on elements). Therefore $\prod M'_\lambda\twoheadrightarrow\prod\mathrm{im}\,f_\lambda$ is an epimorphism. By the universal property of the image, there is a comparison map $\mathrm{im}(\prod f_\lambda)\to\prod\mathrm{im}\,f_\lambda$ that commutes with the epimorphisms $\prod M'_\lambda\twoheadrightarrow\prod\mathrm{im}\,f_\lambda$ and $\prod M'_\lambda\twoheadrightarrow\mathrm{im}(\prod f_\lambda)$, and commutes with the monomorphisms $\prod\mathrm{im}\,f_\lambda\hookrightarrow\prod M_\lambda$ and $\mathrm{im}(\prod f_\lambda)\hookrightarrow\prod M_\lambda$. Therefore, the comparison map $\mathrm{im}(\prod f_\lambda)\to\prod\mathrm{im}\,f_\lambda$ is both an epimorphism and a monomorphism, and hence an isomorphism, since we are working in the category of modules. Therefore products commute with images, and therefore we are done.