# $M_1 \oplus M_2$ is projective $\iff M_1$ and $M_2$ are both projective

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

**If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are R-modules, $R$ possibly non-commutative. Show that
$M_1 \oplus M_2$ is projective $\iff M_1$ and $M_2$ are both projective**

I have no idea how to solve this. By definition an $R$-module is defined to be projective if the functor  $Hom_R(P,−): RMod \to Ab$ is exact. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can show that an $R$-module $M$ is projective iff there exists $F,N$ $R$-modules such that $F$ is free and $F \cong M\oplus N$.

Comment: Dummit and Foote 3rd ed. Abstract Algebra, Section 10.5 has some decent material on this.

Comment: @simo210 Do you know where I can find a proof of that?

Comment: @darkside: For one, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4809849/742).

Answer (score 3):

You use the universal property of the coproduct (i.e. direct sum in our case) to see that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M_1\oplus M_2,-)\cong\mathrm{Hom}_R(M_1,-)\times\mathrm{Hom}_R(M_2,-)$ as functors $\mathrm{Mod}_R\to\mathrm{Ab}$. Now, a product of functors is exact iff all the functors involved are exact. This is essentially immedate from the proposition in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4808111/1179406), which is not hard to prove by checking things on elements. (And I gave in there also a proof which tries to avoid elementwise arguments as much as possible.)

Edit: for a proof using that a module is free if it has left lifting against surjections, we first prove that if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are both projective, so is their sum $M_1\oplus M_2$. Suppose given a surjection $g\colon N\twoheadrightarrow N'$, and a map $h\colon M_1\oplus M_2\to N'$. Such a map $h$ is of the form $h(m_1,m_2)=h_1(m_1)+h_2(m_2)$ for some $h_i\colon M_i\to N'$. Since $M_1$ and $M_2$ are projective, we can lift either $h_i$ to a map $\widetilde{h}_i\colon M_i\to N$ such that $g\widetilde{h}_i=h_i$. Define $\widetilde{h}\colon M_1\oplus M_2\to N, (m_1,m_2)\mapsto \widetilde{h}_1(m_1)+\widetilde{h}_2(m_2)$. Then this is an $R$-linear map, and $g\widetilde{h}=h$. Therefore, $M_1\oplus M_2$ is projective.

Conversely, if $M_1\oplus M_2$ is projective, we will prove that $M_1$ is projective. For a surjection $g\colon N\twoheadrightarrow N'$ and a map $h\colon M_1\to N'$, we define a map $p_1\colon M_1\oplus M_2\to M_1, (m_1,m_2)\mapsto m_1$ and consider the composition $k:=hp_1\colon M_1\oplus M_2\to N'$. We can lift this to a map $\widetilde{k}\colon M_1\oplus M_2\to N$ such that $g\widetilde{k}=k$, because $M_1\oplus M_2$ is projective. Now put $\widetilde{h}\colon M_1\to N, m_1\mapsto \widetilde{k}(m_1,0)$. Then $g\widetilde{h}(m_1)=g\widetilde{k}(m_1,0)=hp_1(m_1,0)=h(m_1)$, so $\widetilde{h}$ is the desired lift that shows that $M_1$ is projective.

Comment: How can I do this without limits and colimits? those are things I have not seen, so I', trying to prove a simpler version for only 2 modules

Comment: You mean you want to prove that $M_1\oplus M_2$ is projective iff both summands are, without using limits and colimits? Then you would need to use a different definition of being projective than that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,-)$ is exact. For instance the lifting description in you other question works, if you know how to relate maps $M_1\oplus M_2\to N$ to a pair maps $M_1\to N$ and $M_2\to N$. I will edit this in.

Comment: Yes I meant that, Thank you I guess I can use that lifting property now that I it has been proven

Comment: Yes I think we can relate those maps with the categorical definition of product, but I haven't been able to successfully get to the answer

Comment: I have edited a solution using this definition.

Comment: Thank you, if you don't mind, could you take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4811126/if-m-1-and-m-2-are-r-modules-r-commutative-show-that-m-1-oplus-m-2-is?noredirect=1#comment10235233_4811126 ?  I should be missing just a small step I think

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem.** $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,-)\colon \mathsf{RMod}\to\mathsf{Ab}$ is exact if and only if for every surjection $f\colon M\to N$ in $\mathsf{RMod}$ and every $h\colon P\to N$, there exists $g\colon P\to M$ such that $fg=h$.

*Proof.* Assume $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,-)$ is exact. Let $f\colon M\to N$ be surjective, and $h\colon P\to N$ be any morphism.

Since $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,-)$ is exact, $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,f)\colon \mathrm{Hom}_R(P,M)\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,N)$ is surjective. Therefore, there exists $g\in\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,M)$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,f)(g)=h$; but $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,f)(g)=fg$, so there exists $g\colon P\to M$ such that $fg=h$.

Conversely, assume the property holds. To show the functor is exact it suffices to show that if $A\stackrel{f}{\to}B\stackrel{g}{\to}C$ are left $R$-modules and module homomorphisms such that $\mathrm{Im}(f)=\ker(g)$, then $\mathrm{Im}(f\circ -)=\mathrm{ker}(g\circ -)$, where
$$f\circ -\colon\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,A)\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,B),\qquad g\circ -\colon \mathrm{Hom}_R(P,B)\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,C).$$
Since $g\circ f$ is the zero map, $(g\circ -)\circ (f\circ -) = (g\circ f)\circ -$ is the zero map.

Now let $h\colon P\to B$ be such that $g\circ h$ is the zero map. Then $h(P)\subseteq \ker(g)=\mathrm{Im}(f)$. Let $f'\colon A\to\mathrm{Im}(f)$ be the correstriction of $f$, $h'\colon P\to  \mathrm{Im}(f)$ be the correstriction of $h$, and let $i\colon\mathrm{Im}(f)\hookrightarrow B$ be the inclusion map. Since $f'$ is surjective, the property says that there exists $u\colon P\to A$ such that $f'\circ u = h'$. Therefore, $f\circ u = i\circ f'\circ u = i\circ h'=h$, so $h$ lies in the image of $f\circ -$. Thus, we have $\mathrm{Im}(f\circ -) = \ker(g\circ -)$, as  desired. $\Box$

**Corollary.** For a left $R$-module $P$, the following are equivalent:

1. $\mathrm{Hom}_R(P,-)\colon\mathsf{RMod}\to\mathsf{Ab}$ is exact.
2. For every surjective homomorphism $f\colon M\to N$ of $R$-modules  and every morphism $h\colon P\to N$, there exists $g\colon P\to M$ such that $fg=h$.
3. For  every surjecion $f\colon M\to P$, there exists $g\colon P\to M$ such that $fg=\mathrm{id}_P$.
4. $P$ is a direct summand of a free $R$-module; that is, there exists an $R$-module $Q$ such that $P\oplus Q$ is free.

*Proof.* The equivalence of 1 and 2 is the Theorem. The equivalence of 2, 3, and 4 is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4809849/742).

A module satisfying any (and hence all) of the above four conditions is said to be "projective."

**Corollary.** Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be $R$-modules. Then $M_1\oplus M_2$ is projective if and only if $M_1$ and $M_2$ projective.

*Proof.* If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are projective, then there exist $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ sucht hat $M_i\oplus Q_i$ is free, and then $(M_1\oplus M_2)\oplus (Q_1\oplus Q_2)$ is a direct sum of free modules, hence free. Converseley, if $M_1\oplus M_2$ is projective, there exists $Q$ such that $(M_1\oplus M_2)\oplus Q = F$ is free. Then $M_1$ is free, witnessed by $M_1\oplus (M_2\oplus Q)=F$, and $M_2$ is free, witnessed by $M_2\oplus (M_1\oplus Q)\cong F$. $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

*I want to include a proof of Daniel's initial answer.*

---

Take $L\in Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,X)$, then define:
$$[\color{purple}{\eta_{X}}(L)]:= (L_1,L_2)$$
where $\color{purple}{L_1}(m_1) := L((m_1,0))$ and $\color{purple}{L_2}(m_2) := L((0,m_2)).$
These are right $R$-linear maps as $L$ is AND operations are component-wise in $M_1\oplus M_2$ by definition. 
Since the codomain of $L$ is $X$, each $L_i$ takes image in $X$. So we have well definition:
$$\eta_X(L)\in Hom(M_1,X)\times Hom(M_2,X).$$
To show this map is invertible, define:
$$\color{purple}{\eta_X^{-1}}((L_a,L_b)) := L'$$
where $\color{purple}{L'}((m_1,m_2)):= L_a(m_1)+L_b(m_2)$.
This is a right $R$-linear map due to component wise operations in the direct sum AND because the $L_i$ are such maps. Because the codomain of the $L_i$'s is $X$ and $X$ is closed under its own $+$ operation, the image of $L'$ is in $X$. So $$\eta_X^{-1}((L_a,L_b))\in Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,X).$$

---

Now, $$[\eta_X^{-1} \circ \eta_X(L)](m_1,m_2) = L_1(m_1)+L_2(m_2) = L((m_1,0)+(0,m_2)) = L((m_1,m_2))$$
and likewise:
$$\eta_X\circ \eta_X^{-1}(L_a,L_b) = (L_1,L_2),$$
where $L_1(m_1):= (L_a+L_b)((m_1,0)) = L_a(m_1)+L_b(0) = L_a(m_1)$ and similarly $L_2(m_2) = L_b(m_2)$.
Hence both compositions yield their respective identities and $$\eta_X:Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,X)\to Hom(M_1,X)\times Hom(M_2,X)$$
is an *isomorphism* for arbitrary $X$.

---

It remains to check the following commutativity conditions are satisfied, to make $\eta$ **natural**:
$$\color{blue}{\big[\eta_Y\circ F(f) = G(f)\circ \eta_X\big](Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,X))}$$
with
$$\color{purple}{F(X)}:= Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,X)\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\color{purple}{G(X)}:= Hom(M_1,X)\times Hom(M_2,X).$$
Accordingly, inserting the argument:
$$(\eta_Y\circ F(f))(Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,X)) = \eta_Y(Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,Y))$$
$$= Hom(M_1,Y)\times Hom(M_2,Y)$$
$$= G(f)\big(Hom(M_1,X)\times Hom(M_2,X)\big)$$
$$= (G(f)\circ \eta_X)(Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,X)).$$

---

We conclude $Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,\cdot)\cong Hom(M_1,\cdot)\times Hom(M_2,\cdot)$ as functors in $[Mod_R,Ab]$. $\square$

---

---

As for the other remark. Consider a short exact sequence:
$$0\to X \xrightarrow{\color{purple}{\alpha}} Y \xrightarrow{\color{purple}{\beta}} Z\to 0$$
We know exactness at each node implies respectively:
$$\color{darkblue}{ker(\alpha) = \{0\},\text{ }Im(\alpha)=ker(\beta),\text{ and }Im(\beta) = cod(\beta)}.$$
Since the direct product of morphisms just direct products the domains and codomains, we have $ker$ and $Im$ separate as desired:
$$ker\big(Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,\gamma)\big) = ker\big(Hom(M_1,\gamma)\big)\times ker\big(Hom(M_2,\gamma)\big)$$
$$\text{ and }$$
$$Im\big(Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,\gamma)\big) = Im\big(Hom(M_1,\gamma)\big)\times Im\big(Hom(M_2,\gamma)\big).$$
From this, it is apparent that the three statements above in $\color{darkblue}{\text{darkblue}}$ are satisfied by $Hom(M_1\oplus M_2,\gamma)$ iff they are satisfied by both $Hom(M_i,\gamma)$, using $\gamma := \alpha\text{ or }\beta$.

---

So we see that exactness transfers from $F$ to and from the constituent functors. Finally proving $M_1\oplus M_2$ projective iff $M_1$ and $M_2$ are projective. $\square$